# Why did Henry Cameron say that Howard would have to fight Gail Wynand?

Tags: ayn-rand, the-fountainhead

Towards the end of his life, Henry Cameron told Howard Roark that he didn't hate anyone anymore, just Gail Wynand because he represented "the triumph of overbearing vulgarity." He told Howard that he'd have to fight Wynand. (The irony, of course, is that Wynand later became a major client and close personal friend to Howard).

We learn later, of course, that Wynand didn't create that, he just profited off it. On the other hand, Ellsworth Toohey both understands - and is actively causing - the problem, to the point that Stephen Mallory took a shot at him over it.

Why did Cameron think that the problem was Wynand whereas Mallory recognized that it was actually Toohey? Did Cameron just not know about Toohey, or did he misjudge Wynand and Toohey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gail through his newspaper always criticized the great work of talented artists. And the people with no understanding of arts used to follow his newspaper's views and never gave talented artists what they deserved. Howard Roark was a talented young artist with a rich taste of architecture. This means if he want to be recognized for his work, he will have to fight with Gail. And if you remember earlier in the Book Gail did tell Howard to not to build houses as he wants but latter he did allowed him to build as he wants to build and never said anything against him in his newspaper. Also Toohey was a cunning man who never showed his real face to anyone so it was very difficult to blame him. And Gail with his newspaper had a greater effect on the people than Toohey.